# JQuery ui tabs using class selector

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-tabs

In the jquery ui demo, in order to link to a certain tab, id selectors are used, which works fine in links since '#' stands for an anchor in a link.

However I want to create multiple tabpanels and link to the correct tabs using the class selector.

```
<div class="accordion">
    <h3>Product x</h3>
    <div class="tabs">
        <ul>
            <!-- .tabs-0 & .tabs-1 don't work, since they are not a valid url -->
            <li><a href=".tabs-0">General product info</a></li>
            <li><a href=".tabs-1">End user info</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tabs-0">
            general info for product x.
        </div>
        <div class="tabs-1">
            end user info product x.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">
    <h3>Product y</h3>
    <div class="tabs">
        <ul>
            <!-- .tabs-0 & .tabs-1 don't work, since they are not a valid url -->
            <li><a href=".tabs-0">General info</a></li>
            <li><a href=".tabs-1">End user info</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tabs-0">
            general info for product y.
        </div>
        <div class="tabs-1">
            end user info product y.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/H5NZD/) is what I tried in jsfidlle and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/S74p8/1/) is how each panel should look like!

So the question is how do I link to the tabs by class name?

Comment: placing jquery code than html markup would be better!

Comment: jquery code works fine, the problem are the links .tabs-0 and .tabs-1 inside the a tags!

Comment: Is there a specific reason you can't assign an ID to the divs?

Comment: I need to loop through a list of items and show different tabpanels for each item.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li><a href=".tabs-0">General product info</a></li>
<li><a href=".tabs-1">End user info</a></li>
```

The problem lies in the above code.  You [can't use](http://jsfiddle.net/S74p8/3/) `class` for hyper-linking the `a` tag.  So change to `id`s.

Comment: I already know the problem and mentioned that in html comments! The question is how to use class selectors instead of id's!?

Comment: @J.Rahmati That is where the answer lies.  You cannot do like it(only individual)

Comment: I think, I messed up the part where I wanted to show how each panel should look like. I update the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/S74p8/6/

Comment: @J.Rahmati I understood that parts, the problem lies in hyper-linking the class (which is not possible).  It is a kind nested accordion, let me try it

Comment: And I think that by assigning an onclick event to the a tags it should somehow be possible!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, You can use `$(".tabs, .tab1")` selectors. Every section need unique id so that it can able to show or hide that respective section, else it couldn't able to select!

```
    <div class="accordion">
        <h3>Product x</h3>
        <div class="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-0">General product info</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-1">End user info</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tabs-0">
                general info for product x.
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-1">
                end user info product x.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accordion">
        <h3>Product y</h3>
        <div class="tab1" >
            <ul>            
                <li><a href="#tab1-0">General info</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab1-1">End user info</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tab1-0" >
                general info for product y.
            </div>
            <div id="tab1-1" >
                end user info product y.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Script:

```
$(".tabs, .tab1").tabs();
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/S74p8/4/

Comment: I don't want to manually set the id's! That is why I want to use class instead of id's

Comment: Is it possible to generate that using jquery?

Comment: You want to generate the html element using jquery! yes you can

Answer (score 0):

In the end I came up with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/UyMV6/):

HTML:

```
<div class="accordion">
    <h3>Product x</h3>
    <div class="tabs">
        <ul>
            <!-- .tabs-0 & .tabs-1 don't work, since they are not a valid url -->
            <li><a href="" class="tabpanellink">General product info</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="tabpanellink">End user info</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tabpanel">
            general info for product x.
        </div>
        <div class="tabpanel">
            end user info product x.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">
    <h3>Product y</h3>
    <div class="tabs">
        <ul>
            <!-- .tabs-0 & .tabs-1 don't work, since they are not a valid url -->
            <li><a href="" class="tabpanellink">General info</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="tabpanellink">End user info</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tabpanel">
            general info for product y.
        </div>
        <div class="tabpanel">
            end user info product y.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(".tabpanellink").each(
    function(uniqueindex){
        $(this).attr('href', '#tab-' + uniqueindex);
    }
);
$(".tabpanel").each(
    function(uniqueindex){
        $(this).attr('id', 'tab-' + uniqueindex);
    }
);

$(".accordion").accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: false
});
$(".tabs").tabs();
```